# json.Marshal(struct) returns "{}"

Tags: json, go, marshalling

```
type TestObject struct {
    kind string `json:"kind"`
    id   string `json:"id, omitempty"`
    name  string `json:"name"`
    email string `json:"email"`
}

func TestCreateSingleItemResponse(t *testing.T) {
    testObject := new(TestObject)
    testObject.kind = "TestObject"
    testObject.id = "f73h5jf8"
    testObject.name = "Yuri Gagarin"
    testObject.email = "Yuri.Gagarin@Vostok.com"

    fmt.Println(testObject)

    b, err := json.Marshal(testObject)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(b[:]))
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[ `go test -test.run="^TestCreateSingleItemResponse$"` | done: 2.195666095s ]
    {TestObject f73h5jf8 Yuri Gagarin Yuri.Gagarin@Vostok.com}
    {}
    PASS
```

Why is the JSON essentially empty?

Answer (score 346, accepted):

You need to [export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields in TestObject by capitalizing the first letter in the field name. Change `kind` to `Kind` and so on.

```
type TestObject struct {
 Kind string `json:"kind"`
 Id   string `json:"id,omitempty"`
 Name  string `json:"name"`
 Email string `json:"email"`
}
```

The encoding/json package and similar packages ignore unexported fields.

The `` `json:"..."` `` strings that follow the field declarations are [struct tags](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag). The tags in this struct set the names of the struct's fields when marshaling to and from JSON.

[Ru it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/n19J5XhiGIL).

Comment: there is supposed to be no "space" before "omitempty"

Comment: Can I make with small letter ?

Comment: If you want small letter tag the fields https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825322/why-golang-cannot-generate-json-from-struct-with-front-lowercase-character

Comment: @user123456 Set the JSON field name to a lowercase name using the `json` field tag (as described in last paragraph of this answer).

Answer (score 35):

- When the first letter is ***capitalised***, the identifier is public to any
  piece of code that you want to use.
- When the first letter is ***lowercase***, the identifier is private and
  could    only be accessed  within the package it was declared.

Examples

```
 var aName // private

 var BigBro // public (exported)

 var 123abc // illegal

 func (p *Person) SetEmail(email string) {  // public because SetEmail() function starts with upper case
    p.email = email
 }

 func (p Person) email() string { // private because email() function starts with lower case
    return p.email
 }
```

Comment: awesome man, work perfect only change first letter to UPPER CASE, thank you so much

Comment: Exactly, `In Go, a name is exported if it begins with a capital letter`.  

To put it in context, visit this [Go Basics Tour](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3)

Answer (score 7):

In golang

> in struct first letter must uppercase
>   ex. phonenumber -> PhoneNumber

======= Add detail

First, I'm try coding like this

```
type Questions struct {
    id           string
    questionDesc string
    questionID   string
    ans          string
    choices      struct {
        choice1 string
        choice2 string
        choice3 string
        choice4 string
    }
}
```

golang compile is not error and not show warning. But response is empty because something

After that, I search google found this article

> Struct Types and Struct Type Literals
>   [Article](https://go101.org/article/struct.html) then... I try edit code.

```
//Questions map field name like database
type Questions struct {
    ID           string
    QuestionDesc string
    QuestionID   string
    Ans          string
    Choices      struct {
        Choice1 string
        Choice2 string
        Choice3 string
        Choice4 string
    }
}
```

Is work.

Hope for help.

Comment: add more details

Comment: Yapp, I add more details.