# How can a function that accepts an interface{} parameter update the value it is called with by reference?

Tags: go

I have a package called `server` that contains a `Settings` struct. It contains code like this:

```
type Settings struct {
    foobar String
}

func example() {
    readSettings := Settings{}
    err := storage.GetSettings(&readSettings)
    // Problem: at this point, readSettings has not been changed!
}
```

My problem is that readSettings is not being updated.

In the `storage` package, there is a function `GetSettings`:

```
func GetSettings(settingsToPopulate interface{}) error {
    file, _ := os.Open("/tmp/settings.json")
    var decodedSettings interface{}
    json.NewDecoder(file).Decode(&decodedSettings)
    settingsToPopulate = decodedSettings
    return nil
}
```

My constraints are that the `Settings` struct must remain in `server`, and the IO method `GetSettings` much remain in `storage`.

I can't make `GetSettings` just accept a `Settings` struct, because that would cause a circular dependency.

How can I make the reference parameter of `GetSettings` be updated?

Comment: You could not passing anything at all and make `GetSettings` return all the values for `Settings` individually. Or you could use a map[string]interface{} as the return value, then convert it to a `Settings`.

Comment: `json.NewDecoder(file).Decode(settingsToPopulate)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json.Marshal(struct) returns "{}"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327391/json-marshalstruct-returns)

Comment: Export the fields. Also, don't forget to Close() the file when you're done with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you don't need to use the intermediate variable `decodedSettings`. Instead, using the `readSettings` pointer you pass in directly will cause the JSON package to deserialise to that instead.

Your code will become:

```golang
func GetSettings(settingsToPopulate interface{}) error {
    file, _ := os.Open("/tmp/settings.json")
    return json.NewDecoder(file).Decode(settingsToPopulate)
}
```