# variable is empty but later has a value

Tags: go, debugging, terraform

I'm trying to develop a Terraform provider but I have a problem of the first request body. Here is the code:

```
type Body struct {
    id string
}

func resourceServerCreate(d *schema.ResourceData, m interface{}) error {
    key := d.Get("key").(string)
    token := d.Get("token").(string)
    workspace_name := d.Get("workspace_name").(string)
    board_name := d.Get("board_name").(string)


    resp, err := http.Post("https://api.trello.com/1/organizations?key="+key+"&token="+token+"&displayName="+workspace_name,"application/json",nil)

    if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    //lettura body.
    body := new(Body)
    json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(body)

    log.Println("[ORCA MADONNA] il log funzia "+body.id)
    d.Set("board_id",body.id)

    resp1, err1 := http.Post("https://api.trello.com/1/boards?key="+key+"&token="+token+"&idOrganization="+body.id+"&=&name="+board_name,"application/json",nil)
    
    if err1 != nil {
            log.Fatalln(resp1)
    }

    defer resp1.Body.Close()
    
    d.SetId(board_name)
    


    return resourceServerRead(d, m)
```

}

In the log is empty, but the second call have it and work fine. How is it possible?

Comment: what is empty in the log? the body.id?

Comment: yeah, but it have no sense because later in the second post body.id is used and work fine

Comment: Strange to `defer` the call to `Decode(body)`.

Comment: you have deferred unmarshalling the resp.Body to `body` object, therefore body.id is expected to be empty

Comment: can you edit the code so we can see the function scope?

Comment: yeah sure, sorry Brand i don't understnad i have to leave to the Decode(i have try all for have this working)

Comment: all scope added

Comment: i remove the defer, but the situation is the same

Comment: handle the error of json decode. also in your error checks you are only logging the error and letting the code execute. do you see any fatal logs during execution

Comment: What is `body`? Unless you've implemented a `json.Unmarshaler` you're not going to have any value in the unexported `id` field.

Comment: in what sense jim i am very noob with go

Comment: and body is the interface i will update the code now

Comment: if someone have time to let me know how to parse correctly my body from post

Comment: You cannot write to an unexported field from another package. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327391/json-marshalstruct-returns, and

Comment: To put what `JimB` is saying another way, `id` is not exported from `main` module's `Body` to json because lowercase identifiers are always private in Go.  Change the name to `Id`.

Answer (score 1):

Go doesn't force you to check error responses, therefore it's easy to make silly mistakes.  Had you checked the return value from [`Decode()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder.Decode), you would have immediately discovered a problem.

```
err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Decode error: ", err)
}
```

> Decode error: json: Unmarshal(non-pointer main.Body)

**So your most immediate fix is to use `&` to pass a pointer to `Decode()`:**

```
json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&body)
```

*Also of note, some programming editors will highlight this mistake for you:*

[image: Decode error]

---

Here's a working demonstration, including a corrected `Body` structure as described at [json.Marshal(struct) returns “{}”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327391/json-marshalstruct-returns):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type JSON = map[string]interface{}
type JSONArray = []interface{}

func ErrFatal(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(msg+": ", err)
    }
}

func handleTestRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    w.Write(([]byte)("{\"id\":\"yourid\"}"))
}

func launchTestServer() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleTestRequest)
    go http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // allow server to get started
}

// Medium: "Don’t use Go’s default HTTP client (in production)"
var restClient = &http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Second * 10,
}

func DoREST(method, url string, headers, payload JSON) *http.Response {

    requestPayload, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    ErrFatal(err, "json.Marshal(payload")

    request, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewBuffer(requestPayload))
    ErrFatal(err, "NewRequest "+method+" "+url)

    for k, v := range headers {
        request.Header.Add(k, v.(string))
    }

    response, err := restClient.Do(request)
    ErrFatal(err, "DoRest client.Do")
    return response
}

type Body struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
}

func clientDemo() {
    response := DoREST("POST", "http://localhost:8080", JSON{}, JSON{})
    defer response.Body.Close()
    var body Body
    err := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&body)
    ErrFatal(err, "Decode")
    fmt.Printf("Body: %#v\n", body)
}

func main() {
    launchTestServer()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        clientDemo()
    }
}
```

Comment: A subtle implementation difference worthy of further investigation: `body := new(Body)` vs `var body Body`

Comment: Regarding `new`: [Pointers vs. values in parameters and return values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57486190/86967)