# retrieve a nested document with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, bson, mgo

I need to retrieve a nested document in mongoDB with mgo.
Here is my document in db:

```
{
    "_id" : "packing_type_0000",
    "name" : "packing",
    "category" : "logistics",
    "en" : {
            "translatedName" : "Packing and Order Prep",
    },
}
```

This is my golang structure:

```
type jobTypeWording struct {
     translatedName     string `json:"translatedName" bson:"translatedName"`
}

type jobType struct {
    ID               string         `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    Name             string         `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Category         string         `json:"category" bson:"category"`
    en               jobTypeWording `json:"en" bson:"en"`
}
```

And my code:

```
result := jobType{}
sessionCopy := session.Copy()
defer sessionCopy.Close()
c := sessionCopy.DB(os.Getenv("DB_DATABASE")).C("jobTypes")
err := c.Find(bson.M{"_id": Id}).One(&result)  
fmt.Println(result.en)
```

My program program output:

```
{  }
```

How do I retrieve `en.translatedName`?

In the same program I get other nested bson from mongo and it's working with same way. I don't understand my mistake.

Comment: Don't ignore errors. What does your `err` say?

Comment: Yes it's for the snippet but `err` say `<nil>`

Comment: Please show us complete, real code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, it's because my field `en` began by a lower case. If i change `en` by `En` and `translatedName` by `TranslatedName`, it's work.
Here a more details [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21825458/4023395)