# Create item in dynamodb using go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the follow code to create a item in my dynamodb table:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/endpoints"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws/external"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"
)

type Record struct {
    ID     string
    URLs   []string
}


// Using the SDK's default configuration, loading additional config
// and credentials values from the environment variables, shared
// credentials, and shared configuration files
var cfg, err = external.LoadDefaultAWSConfig()

func createNewExtraction() error {
    svc := dynamodb.New(cfg)

    r := Record{
        ID:   "ABC123",
        URLs: []string{
            "https://example.com/first/link",
            "https://example.com/second/url",
        },
    }
    item, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("failed to DynamoDB marshal Record, %v", err))
    }

    req := svc.PutItemRequest(&dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        TableName: aws.String("test"), Item: item })

    _, err = req.Send(); if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    if len(cfg.Region) > 0 {
        // Set Region to us-east-1 as default.
        cfg.Region = endpoints.UsEast1RegionID
    }

    err = createNewExtraction(); if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

But it's returning the error:

```
panic: ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item
    status code: 400, request id: F3VCQSGRIG5GM5PEJE7T5M4CEVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /Users/user/go/src/Test2/test.go:56 +0x102
exit status 2
```

I already tried to declare Id, id and ID in my Record struct, but it doesn't work.

The stranger is: I got this code in the official documentation (I'm updating to work with the aws-sdk-go-v2).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the keys of your DynamoDB table? The Partition Key is mandatory in your item and it is case-sensitive.

Comment: @Costin I have only two keys: id and url.

Comment: So use `id` instead of `ID` everywhere. Should you use `URLs` as a sorting key, call it `url` and change it's type, if I remember well it can only be `String`, `Number` or `Binary`.

Comment: I made the updates, and I still see: panic: ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item. Maybe this is happening because I'm using the aws-sdk-go-v2?

Comment: Can you print the `item` that is sent, the one generated here: `item, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(r)`?

Comment: Yes! It's printing `map[]`. Weird, hm..

Comment: If I use uppercase attributes in my struct, it works the MarshalMap: `map[ID:{
  S: "ABC123"
} URLs:{
  L: [{
      S: "https://example.com/first/link"
    },{
      S: "https://example.com/second/url"
    }]
}]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166007/discussion-between-costin-and-driele-reis).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know `golang`, but I had similar problems in `nodejs`.

Make sure the `item` you put in the table contains the 'partition key' and the `sorting key`, case-sensitive.

EDIT:

• It is a `golang` issue, the `item` is not built properly when the DynamoDB column names are lowercase.

• Consider redefining the `Record` structure (see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825322/why-golang-cannot-generate-json-from-struct-with-front-lowercase-character) for details):

```
type Record struct{
    ID     string `json:"id"`
    URLs   []string `json:"url"`
}
```

where `id` and `url` are column names in DynamoDB table.

Comment: Well well, I guess there should be a note about this at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/dynamo-example-create-table-item.html. It's fairly misleading once DynamoDB expects a pattern that's a "private" to golang's struct.