# Why does this TOML table not parse correctly in Go

Tags: go, toml

I'm relatively new to Golang. I've been trying to solve this issue for a little while but have not found anything to help me. I am just trying to parse a `config.toml` file into my application.

My `config.toml` file is as follows:

```
[[trees]]
name = "test1"
tags = ["main", "dev"]

[[trees]]
name = "test2"
tags = ["main", "dev", "prod"]
```

And the code which I am using to read the file:

```
import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    toml "github.com/pelletier/go-toml/v2"
)

type Configuration struct {
    Trees    []tree `toml:"trees"`
}
type tree struct {
    name    string `toml:"name"`
    tags    []string `toml:"tags"`
}

func main() Configuration {
    doc, e := os.ReadFile("config.toml")
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
    var cfg Configuration
    err := toml.Unmarshal(doc, &cfg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(cfg.Trees)
    return cfg
}
```

When I execute the code, I get the following empty array as an output:
`> [{ []} { []}]`

If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong here, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capitalize the struct field names:

```golang
type Configuration struct {
    Trees    []tree `toml:"trees"`
}
type tree struct {
    Name    string `toml:"name"`
    Tags    []string `toml:"tags"`
}
```

Here's a related explanation for [`json.Marshal`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825322/why-golang-cannot-generate-json-from-struct-with-front-lowercase-character): the structure fields need to be public (ie, uppercase names).

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea about this quirk. Have a good day