# Why struct fields are showing empty?

Tags: json, go, struct

I am struggling to get the correct output from the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    var jsonBlob3 = []byte(`[
        {"name": "Platypus", "spec": "Monotremata", "id":25 },
        {"name": "Quoll",    "spec": "Dasyuromorphia", "id":25 }
    ]`)
    type Animal2 struct {
        name  string
        spec string
        id uint32
    }
    var animals []Animal2
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonBlob3, &animals)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", animals)
}
```

Playground [snippet](http://play.golang.org/p/s-T2QAjaDr)

The struct fields are empty when printed. I am sure there is a dumb mistake somewhere but I am still new to Go and I have been stuck at this for hours. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lowercase JSON key names with JSON Marshal in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11693865/lowercase-json-key-names-with-json-marshal-in-go)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has come up so many times. The problem is that only exported fields can be marshaled/unmarshaled.

Export the struct fields by starting them with capital (upper-case) letters.

```
type Animal2 struct {
    Name string
    Spec string
    Id   uint32
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/rZe0qTL86_).

Note that the JSON text contains the field names with lowercased text, but the `json` package is "clever" enough to match them. If they would be completely different, you could use struct tags to tell the `json` package how they are found (or how they should be marshaled) in the JSON text, e.g.:

```
type Animal2 struct {
    Name string `json:"json_name"`
    Spec string `json:"specification"`
    Id   uint32 `json:"some_custom_id"`
}
```