# Umarshalling JSON results in empty struct

Tags: arrays, json, go, slice

I have the following JSON structure:

```
dataJson := `{"data1" : [["a",1]["b",2]], "data2": ["a","b",3]}`
```

And want to unmarshal it with Go. I am trying the following code:

```
type myData struct {
    row    map[string][][]interface{} `json:"data1"`
    column map[string][]interface{}   `json:"data2"`
}

var arr myData

_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJson), &arr)
```

But I get empty data:

```
Unmarshaled: {map[] map[]}
```

Any idea how to parse such JSON structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that struct fields must be exported (start their name with uppercased letters). See [Why struct fields are showing empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674913/why-struct-fields-are-showing-empty/32674930#32674930) for more details.

Next, your input JSON is invalid, you have a missing comma between elements of `data1` array. It should be:

```
{"data1" : [["a",1],["b",2]], "data2": ["a","b",3]}
```

Third, `data1` and `data2` are JSON arrays, so you have to use a slice in Go and not a map.

Something like this:

```
type myData struct {
    Row    [][]interface{} `json:"data1"`
    Column []interface{}   `json:"data2"`
}
```

[`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) returns an error, never omit errors in Go. The least you can do is print them so you'll know something's not right:

```
dataJson := `{"data1" : [["a",1],["b",2]], "data2": ["a","b",3]}`

var arr myData
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(dataJson), &arr); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
log.Printf("Unmarshaled: %v", arr)
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0on7sZPkKKj)):

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Unmarshaled: {[[a 1] [b 2]] [a b 3]}
```